# Why is numpy converting floats to string during an array conversion?

Tags: python, numpy

I am seeing something strange.  I have an initial python list of strings where the you can consider the strings as the rows in a table with the first row containing the header labels.  I want this in a numpy array.  However when I convert the python list to a numpy array the values in the list seem to be converted back to strings unless I don't include the header row in the numpy array.  Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
mylist = ['Col1,Col2,Col3,Label','1,2,3,0','2,2,2,0','3,3,3,0']
X = []

for line in range(len(mylist)):
    sp = mylist[line].split(',')
    if line != 0:
        sp = [float(element) for element in sp]
        X.append(sp)
    else:
        # Header labels
        X.append(sp)
        
print(X)     
W = np.array(X)
print(W)
```

You can see the output here where the first line is before the conversion of the list to an numpy array and the second line is after the conversion.

```
[['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Label'], [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 0.0], [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.0], [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 0.0]]
[['Col1' 'Col2' 'Col3' 'Label']
 ['1.0' '2.0' '3.0' '0.0']
 ['2.0' '2.0' '2.0' '0.0']
 ['3.0' '3.0' '3.0' '0.0']]
```

If I remove the appending of the header row then it works...of course without the header array but the types are correct:

```
mylist = ['Col1,Col2,Col3,Label','1,2,3,0','2,2,2,0','3,3,3,0']
X = []

for line in range(len(mylist)):
    sp = mylist[line].split(',')
    if line != 0:
        sp = [float(element) for element in sp]
        X.append(sp)
        
print(X)     
W = np.array(X)
print(W)
```

Output:

```
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 0.0], [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.0], [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 0.0]]
[[1. 2. 3. 0.]
 [2. 2. 2. 0.]
 [3. 3. 3. 0.]]
```

Comment: `numpy` arrays don't have a separate 'header'.  Use pandas if you need that.  You can also specify a header when writing an array to a csv file with `savetxt`

Answer (score 1):

When converting a list of strings and numbers to a numpy array, the array will be set to a string `dtype` (in this case, `'<U32'`) so that they are all the same data type. If you want a mix of strings and numbers, then you can tell numpy to create the array with `dtype=object`. But the speed of numpy is only realized when using a consistent data type, preferably a numerical data type.

```py
W = np.array(X, dtype=object)
```

If you want a mix of data types, you're probably better off using a python list. Alternatively, your example seems better suited for pandas, where you can create a `DataFrame` with the column names and data you specified.

Answer (score 0):

numpy is written in C, therefore, numpy behave very similarly to C arrays in most circumstances. This means that numpy arrays have a specific type attached to them, and everything in the array must be of that type. Therefore, when you add the header to `W`, it automatically sets the type of the array to a string and tries to convert anything added to it to a string as well. This is why the numbers are converted to strings when added.

This is different to how python lists work since they don't have any specific type attached to them, allowing you to mix and match different types in the same list.

To fix the issue, you can make the type of `W` object, so it will accept objects of any type:

```
W = np.array(X, dtype="object")
```

note that this will make your code slightly slower since now numpy won't know the type of items inside the array. But if the size is small then it doesn't really matter.

Alternatively you could have two separate ararys, one of the column headers and one for the actual values. This way, you will retain more of the speedup that numpy offers:

```
headers = np.array(X[0], dtype=str)
values = np.array(X[1:], dtype=float)
```